# How to append in get HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying get a `html()` in jQuery and append it to some DOM elements but unable to. Please go through the for loop as that is where the error is occurring:

```
$(function() {

    let fig = $("figure").html();

    $("#search-btn").click(function() {

        let content = $("#search-input").val();

        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < content; i++) {
            $("#photos").html() += `<figure>` + fig;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: `$("#search-input").val();` what does it return? An Integer value?

Comment: Yes DPS, the search value returns an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

you can use append() and prepend()
please go throw it, it may help you.

```
$("#photos").append(`<figure>` + fig;)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#photos").html($("#photos").html() + '<figure>' + fig);
```

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/dw5rcfn4/)

Comment: Hey Axel, the code that you suggested is providing three additional  outputs than required for some reason. So when the user enters a number the exact number of photos should pop up but when i try your method it adds three extra outputs to it.

Comment: @Shaun I didn't check the content provided to the `html()` function. If you want to append content to an element using the `html()` function you do it like this: `el.html(el.html() + ExtraContent)` as you can see in the sample. If the result is not what you expect consider what you're appending alongside the current html. Also, don't forget that you're appending content inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable and generate markup and finally append that markup using `html()`.

```
var html = "";
for (i = 0; i < content; i++) {
    html += `<figure>` + fig;
}
$("#photos").html(html);
```

Comment: Hey Shree,  Thanks for the help but I am trying to no use this method of constructing a string. Do you reckon there is any other way to it?

Comment: It's good practice. In loop if you want to append; each time its manipulate with DOM but if you generate string and append ; its manipulate once .Its also good for performance. Choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or concatenation as usual. Template Literal are great, but the only downside is compatibility [ECMAScript6 only].

Using Template Literal will be like this,

```
$("#photos").append(`<figure> ${fig}`);
```

Using concatenation will be like this,

```
$("#photos").append('<figure>' + fig);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried using the concat method but the only issue here is that in the first half line of the line I am trying to get the html from photos div and in the second half I want to append it. This is breaking the code when I try to append it.                                                                                                                          
     $("#photos").html() + (`<figure> ${fig} </figure>`);

Comment: Looking at your code I see you're "fig" is already a figure element. Why to wrap it around another figure. It's easier if you do $("#photos").append(fig). When using concatenation ${} will not work, that would only work inside a Template literal ``.

Answer (score 0):

to fix error use

```
$("#photos").append($('<figure>').html(fig))
```

`.append()` -  adds element as last to selected element
`$('<figure>')` - create jQuery element with tag name "figure"
`.html(fig)` - fill jQuery element with passed string as html

---

NEVER override jQuery's html <strike>`$("#id").html($("#id").html() + addedHtml)`</strike> , because You break events on inner elements

---

also:
`$("#search-input").val()` returns type **string**
to use it in cicle, you must convert value to **number**: `+$("#search-input").val()` - added "**+**"  as easy way, also see "JS parseInt()"

Comment: Thanks very much its working now. Appreciate your help.